# Using Matlab JVM on linux machine java functions work differently?? java.nio.transferTo for example?

Tags: java, linux, windows, matlab

Does anyone know Why when I run this code:

```
function TrimBinary(ifile,ofile,n)

fromfile = java.io.RandomAccessFile(ifile, 'rw');
fromchannel = fromfile.getChannel();
tofile = java.io.FileOutputStream(ofile);
tochannel = tofile.getChannel();
tochannel.position(0);
fromchannel.transferTo(n,fromfile.length()-n,tochannel);

tochannel.close();
fromchannel.close();
fromfile.close();
tofile.close();

end
```

On linux Matlab for the input:

```
00000000h: 05 FF 49 FF F4 FD 13 FF A5 FD A5 20 AC FD 55 FE ; .ÿIÿôý.ÿ¥ý¥ ¬ýUþ
00000010h: 67 FE C7 FF BE FD 75 FE CF FE 28 20 A1 FD 3F FE ; gþÇÿ¾ýuþÏþ( ¡ý?þ
00000020h: 1C FD 4B 20 D0 FD 49 FF 62 FF E7 FF 79 FD CF FE ; .ýK ÐýIÿbÿçÿyýÏþ
00000030h: 20 FD 31 FE 31 FE 46 FE C2 FC EF FE 52 FD F0 FD ;  ý1þ1þFþÂüïþRýðý
00000040h: 40 FD 37 FF 2A FD A5 FD 2F FC EA FF FB FD 92 FE ; @ý7ÿ*ý¥ý/üêÿûý’þ
00000050h: 8C FC 20 80 20 80 83 FE 81 FD 3E FF 39 FD D3 FD ; Œü € €ƒþý>ÿ9ýÓý
00000060h: F1 FC 5E FC 34 FE 79 FD 83 FB 7F 7F 99 FE 2A FD ; ñü^ü4þyýƒû™þ*ý
00000070h: 20 FD AF FD 7A FC 20 80 2A FD 35 FD 20 80 20 80 ;  ý¯ýzü €*ý5ý € €
00000080h: F1 FC AA FB 20 80 20 80 FF FC 12 FC 20 80 20 80 ; ñüªû € €ÿü.ü € €
00000090h: 46 FE D1 FC 20 80 20 80 20 80 5D FD 01 FF 76 FD ; FþÑü € € €]ý.ÿvý
000000a0h: FB FD E6 FC 30 02 40 FD F4 FD A4 FE BA 01 20 80 ; ûýæü0.@ýôý¤þº. €
000000b0h: 46 FE 7B FF AB 01 57 FC BC FF 57 FF 6B 01 80 FE ; Fþ{ÿ«.Wü¼ÿWÿk.€þ
000000c0h: 61 20 3E FF 58 02 68 FD 62 FF 69 FF 4A 01 D3 FD ; a >ÿX.hýbÿiÿJ.Óý
000000d0h: E1 FE 0C FF EA FF 55 FE 49 FF 51 FE EE FF 93 FD ; áþ.ÿêÿUþIÿQþîÿ“ý
000000e0h: F8 20 E2 FD 25 FF CD FC 05 FF 80 FE BE FD D8 FC ; ø âý%ÿÍü.ÿ€þ¾ýØü
```

and n = 106, I get

```
00000000h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000010h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000020h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000030h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000040h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000050h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ; ................
00000060h: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7F 7F 99 FE 2A FD ; ..........™þ*ý
00000070h: 20 FD AF FD 7A FC 20 80 2A FD 35 FD 20 80 20 80 ;  ý¯ýzü €*ý5ý € €
00000080h: F1 FC AA FB 20 80 20 80 FF FC 12 FC 20 80 20 80 ; ñüªû € €ÿü.ü € €
00000090h: 46 FE D1 FC 20 80 20 80 20 80 5D FD 01 FF 76 FD ; FþÑü € € €]ý.ÿvý
000000a0h: FB FD E6 FC 30 02 40 FD F4 FD A4 FE BA 01 20 80 ; ûýæü0.@ýôý¤þº. €
000000b0h: 46 FE 7B FF AB 01 57 FC BC FF 57 FF 6B 01 80 FE ; Fþ{ÿ«.Wü¼ÿWÿk.€þ
000000c0h: 61 20 3E FF 58 02 68 FD 62 FF 69 FF 4A 01 D3 FD ; a >ÿX.hýbÿiÿJ.Óý
000000d0h: E1 FE 0C FF EA FF 55 FE 49 FF 51 FE EE FF 93 FD ; áþ.ÿêÿUþIÿQþîÿ“ý
000000e0h: F8 20 E2 FD 25 FF CD FC 05 FF 80 FE BE FD D8 FC ; ø âý%ÿÍü.ÿ€þ¾ýØü
```

And when I run it on Windows for the same input I get, what I should get and want:

```
00000000h: 7F 7F 99 FE 2A FD 20 FD AF FD 7A FC 20 80 2A FD ; ™þ*ý ý¯ýzü €*ý
00000010h: 35 FD 20 80 20 80 F1 FC AA FB 20 80 20 80 FF FC ; 5ý € €ñüªû € €ÿü
00000020h: 12 FC 20 80 20 80 46 FE D1 FC 20 80 20 80 20 80 ; .ü € €FþÑü € € €
00000030h: 5D FD 01 FF 76 FD FB FD E6 FC 30 02 40 FD F4 FD ; ]ý.ÿvýûýæü0.@ýôý
00000040h: A4 FE BA 01 20 80 46 FE 7B FF AB 01 57 FC BC FF ; ¤þº. €Fþ{ÿ«.Wü¼ÿ
00000050h: 57 FF 6B 01 80 FE 61 20 3E FF 58 02 68 FD 62 FF ; Wÿk.€þa >ÿX.hýbÿ
00000060h: 69 FF 4A 01 D3 FD E1 FE 0C FF EA FF 55 FE 49 FF ; iÿJ.Óýáþ.ÿêÿUþIÿ
00000070h: 51 FE EE FF 93 FD F8 20 E2 FD 25 FF CD FC 05 FF ; Qþîÿ“ýø âý%ÿÍü.ÿ
00000080h: 80 FE BE FD D8 FC                               ; €þ¾ýØü
```

????????

Why am I getting different results using the same java matlab code

Comment: It works fine for me in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit with MATLAB R2013b (Java 1.7.0_11-b21). No leading zeros.

Comment: Im using Java 1.6.0_17-b04. Maybe I should update?

Comment: Well, you can specify JVM 7 by [setting the `MATLAB_JAVA` environment variable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103056), so it's worth a shot.

Comment: Im now using Java 1.7.0_45-b18 and still getting the leading zeros.... Maybe it's because im running OpenSuse Server Linux? I don't know, Ill run on windows for now but, someone should look into this.